# C# : WCF client doesn't connect to same machine

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to make my first WCF program. It should be very simple but I can't manage to get it working.

Steps I have done so far:

1. Create C# windows forms application
2. Adding a button
3. Added a WCF Service to project.
4. Changed the codes according to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/11/02/wcf-101-the-simplest-wcf-example-you-ll-ever-see.aspx?Redirected=true) and [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2007/04/14/a-truely-simple-example-to-get-started-with-wcf.aspx) page tutorials.

**IWCF.cs** code :

```
using System;
...etc

namespace WCF_Application
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWCF
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string DoWork();
    }
}
```

**WCF.cs** code :

```
using System;
...

namespace WCF_Application
{

    public class WCF : IWCF
    {
        public string DoWork()
        {
            return " Hello There! ";
        }

    }
}
```

Button code:

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
// Starting the Server

            ServiceHost svh = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCF));
            svh.AddServiceEndpoint(
                typeof(IWCF),
                new NetTcpBinding(),
                "net.tcp://localhost:8000");
            svh.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connected");

// Connecting Client to the server
            ChannelFactory<IWCF> scf;
            scf = new ChannelFactory<IWCF>(
                        new NetTcpBinding(),
                        "net.tcp://localhost:8000");

            IWCF s = scf.CreateChannel();
            string response = s.DoWork();
            MessageBox.Show(response);
            svh.Close();
}
```

I don't get the response message. The program justs freezes. When I trace the code, the program gets stuck at the `strong response = s.DoWork();` line.

I also checked `netstat -a` in cmd. and it seems the port 8000 does open in listening mode. So the problem should be with the client part.

OS Windows 7 / 
VS 2010 /
C#

Comment: Try putting a break point on the server, does the call actually enter?

Comment: @ImmortalBlue Where exactly ? I don't get what you mean by "on the server".

Comment: Ok, your service class runs, broadly speaking, on a server. In C# land this equates to your service class (in your case the WCF class). Put a break point on the do work return line to see if it's getting called and the return isn't correctly being actioned, or if it's not even getting that far. I'd recommend starting a vanilla WCF project and seeing if that works without any modification.

Comment: @ImmortalBlue Yeah Sure I have tried the break point on "Hello There" line, but it doesn't break (seems doesn't reach that point/line). And.. sorry can you explain what is a vanilla WCF ?

Comment: Vanilla, as in, plain, original, unedited, default ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running into a deadlock issue here because your WCF service is hosted on the same thread as your UI.  You could try the following to host the service on another thread.

```
[ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class WCF : IWCF
{
    public string DoWork()
    {
        return " Hello There! ";
    }
}
```

Here is some background on the [WPF threading model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [UseSynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.usesynchronizationcontext.aspx).  Alternatively, you could thread off the client calls to your service, but that will likely have other UI updating consequences as well.

Comment: Oh you're right, I didn't pay attention to the thread part. Thank you so much! :)